# Error Implementing Undo Redo for an ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, undo-redo

Class ScreenShot: It Contains two ArrayLists ( Will Create an Object from old ArrayLists and save it within then add to Stacks of Undo)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ScreenShot {
private ArrayList<Shapes> shapes;
private ArrayList<Intersection> intersections;

public ArrayList<Shapes> getShapes() {
    return shapes;
}

public void setShapes(ArrayList<Shapes> shapes) {
    this.shapes = shapes;
}

public ArrayList<Intersection> getIntersections() {
    return intersections;
}

public void setIntersections(ArrayList<Intersection> intersections) {
    this.intersections = intersections;
}

}
```

Class Manager that contains the undo redo stacks

```
public class Manager {

public static Stack<ScreenShot> undoStack = new Stack();
public static Stack<ScreenShot> redoStack = new Stack(); 


}
```

the JFrame that Contains the Undo Redo Buttons :

```
public class Canvas extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public static ArrayList<Shapes> shapes;
public Canvas() {
    initComponents();
}                       

private void undoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
  if(Manager.undoStack.isEmpty()==false)
 {
     ScreenShot temp = Manager.undoStack.pop();
     System.out.println(Manager.undoStack.size());
     Manager.redoStack.push(temp);
     redo.setEnabled(true);

     Canvas.prevShapes=(temp.getShapes());

    Canvas.intersects.clear();
     Canvas.intersects = temp.getIntersections();
     if(Manager.undoStack.isEmpty())
         undo.setEnabled(false);
 }
 cc.repaint();  
}                                    

private void redoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
       if(Manager.redoStack.isEmpty()==false)
 {undo.setEnabled(true);
     ScreenShot temp = Manager.redoStack.pop();
     Manager.undoStack.push(temp);
     Canvas.prevShapes= temp.getShapes();
     Canvas.intersects = temp.getIntersections();
     if(Manager.redoStack.isEmpty())
         redo.setEnabled(false);
 }
 cc.repaint();
}
```

I Tried to shorten the Code as Much as Possible . so here is the basic idea i am following the Memento Design pattern for Undo and redo techniques . and it is taking the old array lists and saving them in the stacks correctly . But the Problem that is happening is the old arraylist wont get cleared no matter what happens ( Ps the ArrayList is Static in case that matters )

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information. Short code is very nice, but it should be without compile-time errors.

Comment: In your code, the `Canvas` class is using the `Shapes` class, the `initComponents` method, `redo` & `undo` buttons, and `prevShapes`, `intersects` & `cc` fields; these are all undefined. In the `ScreenShot` class, the `Intersection` class is undefined. You can either leave these parts out if they are not essential or add them - in a shortened version - to your question.

Comment: Can you clarify your question "But the Problem that is happening is the old arraylist wont get cleared no matter what happens" a bit more? If you add an example with steps to show how the problem can happen, it will be easier to find a solution.